# Error handler does not display custom error logs

Tags: php, mysql, slim, illuminate-container

I am trying to use the custom error handler in slim 4, but it still seems to be using the PHP built in one, here's an output of the error.

[image]

This is what I have tried so far from [here](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/middleware/error-handling.html)

```
$app->addRoutingMiddleware();
$app->addErrorMiddleware(true, true, true);
```

but it seems to have no effect on the error outcome, no matter what options I choose, I have also tried to use the custom renderer from the examples, but this doesn't work either.

Here is my `index.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;
use Slim\Psr7\Request;
use Slim\Psr7\Response;

session_start();
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


$app = AppFactory::create();

/**
 * The routing middleware should be added earlier than the ErrorMiddleware
 * Otherwise exceptions thrown from it will not be handled by the middleware
 */
$app->addRoutingMiddleware();
$app->addErrorMiddleware(true, true, true);


/**
 * Database
 */
$capsule = new Capsule;
$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => 'mysql',
    'database' => 'nuxt-auth',
    'username' => 'root',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
]);


// Make this Capsule instance available globally via static methods... (optional)
$capsule->setAsGlobal();
$capsule->bootEloquent();
$schema = $capsule->getDatabaseManager()->getSchemaBuilder();

/**
 * Init db
 */
if (!$schema->hasTable('users')) {
    $schema->create('users', function ($table) {
       //TODO: write schema
    });
}

$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello World");
    return $response;
});
$app->run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The ErrorMiddleware is able to catch all Exceptions only after running the middleware stack. This happens when you invoke the `$app->run();` method. You may try to create the Capsule instance within a DI container instead.

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work either, the error message is still in the same format uncaught.